# ActionBar doesn't shows up when installed to Android Gingerbread

Tags: java, android, xml, development-environment

I've used a custom Dialog theme which i name poptheme and when i installed it to Gingerbread, the action bar doesn't shows up but when i installed it to Kitkat it works fine.

Since it's a dialog theme, a customized a new theme because i can't put an action bar using the theme theme.dialog. It worked fine on my phone which has Kitkat version, but when i try to run it on Gingerbread version, the layout is not what i wanted it to look like.

This is the code in my onCreate() for the customized dialog theme:

```
 this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    LayoutParams params = this.getWindow().getAttributes(); 
    params.alpha = 1.0f;
    params.dimAmount = 0.7f;
    params.height=250;
    params.width=420;


    this.getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params); 

    // This sets the window size, while working around the IllegalStateException thrown by ActionBarView
   // this.getWindow().setLayout(420,250);
  //  this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  //getWindow().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR` was added in API 11 (Android 3.0) so this approach won't work for Gingerbread (API 9/10).

You will need to use [Android support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

In below **API 11**  Action Bar Showed as a menu
click on Menu Button to see your Action Bar

Action Bar Features  was Added in API 11 .
For Backward Compatibility Please use

***ActionBarSherlock***

[Actionbar sherlock link](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)